# Using PHP Google Photos Api with Server-To-Server communication

Tags: php, google-photos-api, server-to-server

I want to access the google photos via a web server. I.e. My webserver should call the google api and show pictures to me.
I have created a service account in google and created also a public/private key. But I am having an issue with the php photos library with the following error message:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Google\Photos\Library\V1\Gapic\PhotosLibraryGapicClient::__construct() must be of the type array, object given

Any ideas how to get the json credentials loaded for the PhotoLibraryClient?
Thank you!

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=myJson.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$photosLibraryClient = new PhotosLibraryClient($client);
```

Comment: The Lib constructor is expecting an array and the docs examples show that.              `new PhotosLibraryClient(['credentials' => $authCredentials]);`

Comment: yes, but they are using `UserRefreshCredentials` in the array and I want to use my json for server-to-server authentification.
EDIT: just found this comment: _Note that the Library API does not support service accounts._